# Trying to get 2 maps API: FusionTablesLayer Functions to work on the same map and fusion table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have created a fusion table and layer that allows me to use check boxes to hide or display certain markers on the map. I would like to add a search feature that works like the pan and zoom feature. In addition, once the map zooms to the location I would like to have a radius option that identifies other locations within a certain area. 
I have modified the sample code found on the IN Query (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/in) and can get the checkboxes to work, but when I try to include the pan and zoom code (https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/search_and_zoom), I can't seem to get the search feature to work.

I have one fusion table with approximately 4000 records. I am a novice at coding so I am sure it is something in my syntax. I would also assume what I want to do is possible?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code. As indicated I want to insert a search that utilizes pan and zoom feature. I ended up removing it from the code below because I was unsure how to insert or format it.

```
 <head>
  <style>
    #map-canvas { width:800px; height:600px; }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var layerl0;
function initialize() {
        var tableId = '4422804';

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.792047064406866, -99.052734375),
          zoom: 2,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        });

        var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer();
        filterMap(layer, tableId, map);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('< 5'),
            'click', function() {
              filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('> 5'),
            'click', function() {
              filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
        });

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Not Signed'),
            'click', function() {
              filterMap(layer, tableId, map);
        });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('Signed Not Selling'),
            'click', function() {
              filterMap(layer, tableId, map);

    });
      }

      // Filter the map based on checkbox selection.
      function filterMap(layer, tableId, map) {
        var where = generateWhere();

        if (where) {
          if (!layer.getMap()) {
            layer.setMap(map);
          }
          layer.setOptions({
            query: {
              select: 'Full Address',
              from: tableId,
              where: where
            }
          });
        } else {
          layer.setMap(null);
        }
      }

      // Generate a where clause from the checkboxes. If no boxes
      // are checked, return an empty string.
      function generateWhere() {
        var filter = [];
        var stores = document.getElementsByName('store');
        for (var i = 0, store; store = stores[i]; i++) {
          if (store.checked) {
            var storeName = store.value.replace(/'/g, '\\\'');
            filter.push("'" + storeName + "'");
          }
        }
        var where = '';
        if (filter.length) {
          where = "'Map' IN (" + filter.join(',') + ')';
        }
        return where;
      }
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Can't provide much help if you don't have a link to your application or post the code.

Comment: Sorry Eric. Just posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

You did not include your checkboxes, etc.  But here's an example which works, using buttons, not checkboxes. Should not be too hard to adapt it your needs.  No zoom to, which is really a different questions.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebridger/wmnDU/

Comment: Thanks Eric. I took out the table id since the original had proprietary data.I rebuilt the table with bogus data and inserted the new table id in the code above so you can see what happens. I need to insert the pan and zoom search with spatial query feature that is illustrated here: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/search_and_zoom). The idea is to have the users execute a search, then have the map zoom to the location and have an option to display other locations in that area. That is what I am having issues with. I can make one or the other work but not all 3.

Comment: Thanks again. I will work with the your corrections and then repost. I needed the checkboxes because I need to show all results and then have the user filter which ones they need to see. As stated I can get those to work, but for some reason when I pasted the code, that piece was dropped.